# Excluding a set of characters from the first two spaces

Tags: regex

I have a problem that i would like to exclude the characters `ZTzt` from the list.

Currently i have a regex

`(.{2,4}[^Ztzt]AB.+)`

Examples that it should not match but are matching 
`ABZ1234`

Example strings that would be tested and should not be matched 
`ABCZ1ABC`
`ABCDZ14ABC`
`ABZ12ABC`
`ABDZ12ABC`

Comment: Try `\b[A-SU-Za-su-z]{2,4}AB[A-SU-Za-su-z]+\b` https://regex101.com/r/jgRCij/1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add a separator at the beginning of the pattern.

If it can be a newline or a space, you would have the following:
`[\n ](.{2,4}[^Ztzt]AB.+)`

As you want to account for the match of the first word (and thus it wouldn't have the separator, you could add this condition with an "or"):
`([\n ]|^)(.{2,4}[^Ztzt]AB.+)`

You probably want this group to not be captured, so you can indicate it:
`(?:[\n ]|^)(.{2,4}[^Ztzt]AB.+)`

Finally, this would match `ABZ12ABC` as well, given that follows the pattern "2 to for characters, then something not 'Ztzt', and then AB ..." . To avoid that, you could specify that the first characters must not be among 'Ztzt':
`(?:[\n ]|^)([^Ztzt]{2,4}[^Ztzt]AB.+)`

But we are sort of repeating the condition so we could just change the number of allowed occurrences:
`(?:[\n ]|^)([^Ztzt]{3,5}AB.+)`

Would this do the trick?
https://regex101.com/r/Lv1yQv/1